# How to retrieve images from database in php

Tags: php, sql, database, image

I have a database which has a table called 'propImages' and there are two columns.- 'pid' and 'location'.

And i have data in the database where multiple images can contained by single pid.
[image contains database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fSzz.png)

now i want to retrieve images from database according to given pid. there can be more than one image.
All i know it there should be an iteration to retrieve images.

I want to display images in HTML .

can you please show me the way to do it in php?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: That seems like a pretty easy task.  Show us the code you wrote and what doesn't work.  ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )  Following a simple PHP-Mysql tutorial would probably show you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
<?php
include 'inc/database.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$propid = $_GET['propid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM propImages WHERE propid='" . $propid . "';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<img src=" . $row['image'] . ">";
}
}
else {
echo "No results";
}
?>
```

in the ***inc/database.php*** :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "database";
?>
```

To see how it works try visiting : **file.php?propid=22**

Comment: Thanks for the great help Shuan :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = "databasename";

     // Create connection
     $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

     //create sql
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `propImages` where pid='$YOUR_PID'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
     $row = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
     //retrive data print here
     if($row > 0){
         while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             echo $col['location'];
         }
     } else {
        echo 'no result found.'; 
     }
?>
```

wish it helps

Comment: a great help! Thanks buddy :D

Comment: please give some point it will help for our reputation. Thanks :)